# Moonlight 4 out-of-browser

Tags: linux, silverlight, ubuntu, out-of-browser, moonlight

I'm trying to launch some of my existing Silverlight apps out-of-browser on Ubuntu and Moonlight 4 Preview. Install the apps was pretty sweet using Firefox and Chrome.

I received the same error message for all samples I tried:

> Fails to execute child process
>   "...some long
>   path.../moonlight/lunar-launcher"
>   (Permission denied)

Any one has a tip?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like either the 'lunar-launcher' app doesn't have execute permissions (run `chmod +x /home/lenovo/.mozilla/firefox/x9y2ruwx.default/extensions/moonlight@novell.com/plugins/moonlight/lunar-launcher` to fix it) or else the directory it is contained in doesn't have the correct permissions (try `chmod +rx /home/lenovo/.mozilla/firefox/x9y2ruwx.default/extensions/moonlight@novell.com/plugins/moonlight` to fix)

Comment: I had no luck with the commands. The error message is not showed anymore, but the application don't run too. Simply nothing happen. Anyone has sucess to run moonlight out-of-browser?

Comment: I've debugged this and found a fix. Will be committing it shortly and the next nightly build should have it.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest nightly build but am still seeing this issue, I have also tried the commands you suggested above. Any more ideas?